# Can't use plt to show an image from the CIFAR-10 dataset in Google Colab

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to show the images part of the CIFAR-10 dataset but for some reason `plt` shows me an axes image instead of the actual image that I want to see.

```
from os import lseek
from cs231n.data_utils import load_CIFAR10
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Xtr, Ytr, Xte, Yte = load_CIFAR10('cs231n/datasets/cifar-10-batches-py')
# print(Xtr[0].shape) Shape is (32, 32, 3) RGB image.
plt.imshow(Xtr[0])
```

In the docs it says that a shape of `(M, N, 3)` is ok for RGB images so I don't know why it doesn't show it. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try
```python
from IPython.display import Image
Image('pic1.png')
```

Comment: Have a look at some of the entries in the `Xtr[0]` array. Does it maybe just contain entirely ones (or zeros)?

Comment: You could try testing an array that you make, e.g., `import numpy as np; X = np.ones((32, 32, 3)); X[:, 20:35, 1] = 0.5  # set a subset of values; plt.imshow(X);`. This should show an axes were the last part is coloured pink.

Comment: @MattPitkin The data is ok - all elements of Xtr are of the shape (32, 32, 3). For your example, it shows the right side of the image as pink. However, it fails to show the real images of the CIFAR dataset.

Comment: The elements of `Xtr` may all be the right shape, but what are the actual values in `Xtr[0]` and what is their type (integers or floats)? Print out `Xtr[0].dtype` and also print out, e.g., `Xtr[0][:, :, 0]` to have a look at some values. If they are integers they must be values between 0 and 255, and if they are floats they must be between 0 and 1. If all valeus are 1 then you'll just get a completely white image.

Comment: @MattPitkin The dtype for both is `float64`. Xtr[0][:, :, 0] results in `[[ 59.  43.  50. ... 158. 152. 148.]
 [ 16.   0.  18. ... 123. 119. 122.]
 [ 25.  16.  49. ... 118. 120. 109.]
 ...
 [208. 201. 198. ... 160.  56.  53.]
 [180. 173. 186. ... 184.  97.  83.]
 [177. 168. 179. ... 216. 151. 123.]]`.

Comment: Ok, try doing `plt.imshow(Xtr[0].astype(int))` to convert them to integers for plotting.

Comment: No problem, I'll add this as an answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the issue is due to the data type of the values in the `Xtr[0]` variable. Given an (M, N, 3) array, which `Xtr[0]` is, the [`imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) function requires the array to either be a float array containing values between 0 and 1, or an integer array containing values between 0 and 255. In this case, `Xtr[0]` is a float array with values between 0 and 255, which is not liked by `imshow`. The simplest solution is to just pass this array as integers to `imshow`, e.g.,

```py
plt.imshow(Xtr[0].astype(int))
```